I am trying to implement CKEditor in My Next App and I am facing some issues in the implementation
So here is the code of the Editor.jsx
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

function EditorComponent() {
    const [blog_body, setBlogBody] = React.useState('<p>Initial content</p>');
    return <Editor blog_Body={blog_body} setBlog_Body={setBlogBody} />;
}

export default EditorComponent;

and here is the code of the Editor.js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import {
    ClassicEditor,
    AccessibilityHelp,
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    Autosave,
    Base64UploadAdapter,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    Code,
    CodeBlock,
    Essentials,
    FindAndReplace,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    FullPage,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    Highlight,
    HorizontalLine,
    HtmlComment,
    HtmlEmbed,
    ImageBlock,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageInline,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageInsertViaUrl,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageTextAlternative,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    Markdown,
    MediaEmbed,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromMarkdownExperimental,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SelectAll,
    ShowBlocks,
    SourceEditing,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    Strikethrough,
    Style,
    Subscript,
    Superscript,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableColumnResize,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextPartLanguage,
    TextTransformation,
    Title,
    TodoList,
    Underline,
    Undo
} from 'ckeditor5';
import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';
function Editor({ blog_Body, setBlog_Body }) {
    const editorContainerRef = useRef(null);
    const editorRef = useRef(null);
    const [isLayoutReady, setIsLayoutReady] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLayoutReady(true);
        return () => setIsLayoutReady(false);
    }, []);
    
    const handleChangeInData = (event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        setBlog_Body(data);
    }
    const editorConfig = {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'undo',
                'redo',
                '|',
                'sourceEditing',
                'showBlocks',
                'findAndReplace',
                'selectAll',
                'textPartLanguage',
                '|',
                'heading',
                'style',
                '|',
                'fontSize',
                'fontFamily',
                'fontColor',
                'fontBackgroundColor',
                '|',
                'bold',
                'italic',
                'underline',
                'strikethrough',
                'subscript',
                'superscript',
                'code',
                'removeFormat',
                '|',
                'specialCharacters',
                'horizontalLine',
                'link',
                'insertImage',
                'mediaEmbed',
                'insertTable',
                'highlight',
                'blockQuote',
                'codeBlock',
                'htmlEmbed',
                '|',
                'alignment',
                '|',
                'bulletedList',
                'numberedList',
                'todoList',
                'outdent',
                'indent',
                '|',
                'accessibilityHelp'
            ],
            shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false
        },
        plugins: [
            AccessibilityHelp,
            Alignment,
            Autoformat,
            AutoImage,
            AutoLink,
            Autosave,
            Base64UploadAdapter,
            BlockQuote,
            Bold,
            Code,
            CodeBlock,
            Essentials,
            FindAndReplace,
            FontBackgroundColor,
            FontColor,
            FontFamily,
            FontSize,
            FullPage,
            GeneralHtmlSupport,
            Heading,
            Highlight,
            HorizontalLine,
            HtmlComment,
            HtmlEmbed,
            ImageBlock,
            ImageCaption,
            ImageInline,
            ImageInsert,
            ImageInsertViaUrl,
            ImageResize,
            ImageStyle,
            ImageTextAlternative,
            ImageToolbar,
            ImageUpload,
            Indent,
            IndentBlock,
            Italic,
            Link,
            LinkImage,
            List,
            ListProperties,
            Markdown,
            MediaEmbed,
            Paragraph,
            PasteFromMarkdownExperimental,
            PasteFromOffice,
            RemoveFormat,
            SelectAll,
            ShowBlocks,
            SourceEditing,
            SpecialCharacters,
            SpecialCharactersArrows,
            SpecialCharactersCurrency,
            SpecialCharactersEssentials,
            SpecialCharactersLatin,
            SpecialCharactersMathematical,
            SpecialCharactersText,
            Strikethrough,
            Style,
            Subscript,
            Superscript,
            Table,
            TableCaption,
            TableCellProperties,
            TableColumnResize,
            TableProperties,
            TableToolbar,
            TextPartLanguage,
            TextTransformation,
            Title,
            TodoList,
            Underline,
            Undo
        ],
        fontFamily: {
            supportAllValues: true
        },
        fontSize: {
            options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
            supportAllValues: true
        },
        heading: {
            options: [
                {
                    model: 'paragraph',
                    title: 'Paragraph',
                    class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading1',
                    view: 'h1',
                    title: 'Heading 1',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading2',
                    view: 'h2',
                    title: 'Heading 2',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading3',
                    view: 'h3',
                    title: 'Heading 3',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading4',
                    view: 'h4',
                    title: 'Heading 4',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading5',
                    view: 'h5',
                    title: 'Heading 5',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading5'
                },
                {
                    model: 'heading6',
                    view: 'h6',
                    title: 'Heading 6',
                    class: 'ck-heading_heading6'
                }
            ]
        },
        htmlSupport: {
            allow: [
                {
                    name: /^.*$/,
                    styles: true,
                    attributes: true,
                    classes: true
                }
            ]
        },
        image: {
            toolbar: [
                'toggleImageCaption',
                'imageTextAlternative',
                '|',
                'imageStyle:inline',
                'imageStyle:wrapText',
                'imageStyle:breakText',
                '|',
                'resizeImage'
            ]
        },
        initialData:
            // here write the Initial Data you want to write when the page gets rendered like j se 1st appearance chaiye
            '<h2>Title</h2>\n <h4>\nwrite your subheading!</h4>\n <p>\nWrite your content here</p>\n',
        link: {
            addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
            defaultProtocol: 'https://',
            decorators: {
                toggleDownloadable: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Downloadable',
                    attributes: {
                        download: 'file'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        list: {
            properties: {
                styles: true,
                startIndex: true,
                reversed: true
            }
        },
        placeholder: 'Type or paste your content here!',
        style: {
            definitions: [
                {
                    name: 'Article category',
                    element: 'h3',
                    classes: ['category']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Title',
                    element: 'h2',
                    classes: ['document-title']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Subtitle',
                    element: 'h3',
                    classes: ['document-subtitle']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Info box',
                    element: 'p',
                    classes: ['info-box']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Side quote',
                    element: 'blockquote',
                    classes: ['side-quote']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Marker',
                    element: 'span',
                    classes: ['marker']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Spoiler',
                    element: 'span',
                    classes: ['spoiler']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Code (dark)',
                    element: 'pre',
                    classes: ['fancy-code', 'fancy-code-dark']
                },
                {
                    name: 'Code (bright)',
                    element: 'pre',
                    classes: ['fancy-code', 'fancy-code-bright']
                }
            ]
        },
        table: {
            contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties']
        }
    };
    return (
        <>
            {/* Editor */}
            <div className="main-container bg-white rounded-md shadow p-4">
                <div className="editor-container editor-container_classic-editor editor-container_include-style" ref={editorContainerRef}>
                    <div className="editor-container__editor">
                        <div ref={editorRef}>
                            {isLayoutReady && (
                                <CKEditor
                                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                                    config={editorConfig}
                                    data={blog_Body}
                                    onChange={handleChangeInData}
                                />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default Editor;

The use case of the EditorComponent is
const [blog_body, setBlogBody] = useState('<h2>Title</h2><p>Write your content here.</p>');
<EditorComponent blog_Body={blog_body} setBlog_Body={setBlogBody} />

I am getting this error
  ⨯ ..\..\node_modules\.pnpm\@ckeditor+ckeditor5-react@8.0.0_ckeditor5@43.0.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\@ckeditor\ckeditor5-react\dist\index.js (5:315) @ eval
 ⨯ ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\user\Editor-Turbo\apps\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/TextEditor/Editor.js:9:83)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/TextEditor/Editor.js (C:\Users\user\Editor-Turbo\apps\next\.next\server\app\blog\createBlog\page.js:338:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\user\Editor-Turbo\apps\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/blog/createBlog/page.tsx:10:87)
    at (ssr)/./src/app/blog/createBlog/page.tsx (C:\Users\user\Editor-Turbo\apps\next\.next\server\app\blog\createBlog\page.js:272:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\user\Editor-Turbo\apps\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
null

I was expecting the implementation of the CKEditor in Next.js App. I tried the same component but it is not working as it should be. I am facing this and i just knew to Next.js
